# Как написать запрос с условием по последнему статусу из другой таблицы?

Tags: sql, oracle

Задание:

> Написать SQL запрос получающий список всех программ, последний статус
> которых 'завершена'. Под последним статусом программы предполагается
> запись с наибольшим значением `id`.
>
> Окончательный набор колонок должен быть: id программы, наименование
> предмета, дата статуса в формате 'ДД.ММ.ГГГГ'.    Результат запроса
> должен быть отсортирован по дате статуса по убыванию

Структура таблиц (на [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3cd32caf926adbbb8628e346c4b0c7c9)):

```
CREATE TABLE PROGRAMMS (
    PROGRAMMID NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL, 
    RECORDID NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL, 
    PERSONID NUMBER(10, 0), 
    OOP_PLACE VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR), 
    METHOD_SUPPORT VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR), 
    CURRENT_CONTROL_FOND VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR), 
    MEDIUM_CONTROL_FOND VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR), 
    DELETED NUMBER(1, 0) NOT NULL, 
    DEL_DATE DATE, 
    BRANCH NUMBER(4, 0) NOT NULL, 
    DISCID NUMBER(10, 0), 
    CREATE_DATE DATE, 
    CREATE_PERSONID NUMBER(10, 0), 
    MISSION_PROBLEM CLOB, 
    PRACTIC_TYPE NUMBER(1, 0), 
    PRACTIC_FORM NUMBER(1, 0), 
    PRACTIC_PLACE NUMBER(1, 0), 
    IS_VALID NUMBER(1, 0) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL, 
    PRACTICE_REPORT_FORM VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR), 
    ADDITIONAL_QUESTION VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR), 
    MATERIAL_TEXT CLOB, 
    EDU_LINK VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    CONSTRAINT PROGRAMMS PRIMARY KEY (PROGRAMMID) ENABLE 
)

CREATE TABLE STATUS (
    STATUSID NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL, 
    PROGRAMMID NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL, 
    STATUS_CODE NUMBER(1, 0) NOT NULL, 
    STATUS_DATE DATE NOT NULL, 
    USERNAME VARCHAR2(25 CHAR),
    COMMENTARY VARCHAR2(1500 CHAR), 
    CONSTRAINT PK_WP_STATUS PRIMARY KEY (STATUSID) ENABLE
)    

CREATE TABLE Guide (
    CODE NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL, 
    NAME VARCHAR2(300 CHAR) NOT NULL, 
    ABBR VARCHAR2(30 CHAR), 
    DEPARTMENT NUMBER(10, 0), 
    DEFAULT_DIV_TYPE NUMBER(10, 0) DEFAULT 1, 
    DIV_PRACTICES NUMBER(1, 0) DEFAULT 0, 
    DIV_LABS NUMBER(1, 0) DEFAULT 0, 
    CORRECTNAME VARCHAR2(150 CHAR), 
    CONSTRAINT Guide PRIMARY KEY (CODE) ENABLE 
)
```

Пробую таким запросом:

```
SELECT PROGRAMMID, NAME, STATUS_DATE
FROM (
    SELECT  
        programmms.ID AS PROGRAMMID,
        name.Name AS NAME,
        status_date.Date  AS STATUS_DATE,
        status.ID AS STATUSID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY programms.ID ORDER BY status_date DESC)AS rn1
    FROM  wp_programms
    INNER JOIN status ON programms.ID=status.PROGRAMMID
    INNER JOIN name ON programms.STATUSID=name.ID
    ) AS t1
WHERE rn=1
AND STATUS_CODE=1
ORDER BY STATUS_DATE DESC
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Comment: Слушайте, кто нибудь, кто часто здесь бывает: меня глючит, или этот вопрос сегодня уже задавали?

Comment: @S.H., вам не кажется) Вот тот вопрос (нужно, вроде, 10К репутации, чтобы удалённые вопросы смотреть) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1173179/17609. Отличается от этого отсутствием картинок с таблицами и запросом.

Comment: Примеры кода следует текстом приводить. Если для решения проблемы надо пару строк добавить изменить, то отвечающему проще скопировать текст и его исправить, а не набирать всё целиком с картинки. Ну и повторять вопросы тоже не следует - лучше править их, учитывая замечания в комментах, типа вот этого моего, про текст, вместо картинок.

Comment: Укажите точно СУБД  и её версию. Замените фотографии на online fiddle или хотя бы набор CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO скриптов плюс требуемый результат для показанных данных.

Comment: А что не получается?  вы же написали запрос, что с ним не так?

Comment: Плюс пока авансом за попытку решения.